# Ошибка с типами данных в С#

Tags: c#, winforms

Привет!У меня при выполнении программа выдал вот такую ошибку.Можете подсказать где я ошибся и как это исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

CalculatorCalories.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ClassLibrary1;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public interface ICalculatorCalories
    {
        int GetIndex(int growthC, int sex);
        float GetCaloriesM(float weightC, float growC, float yearsC);
        float GetCaloriesW(float weightC, float growC, float yearsC);
}

    public partial class CalculatorCalories : Form, ICalculatorCalories
    {

        public CalculatorCalories()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public int growC { get { return Convert.ToInt32(growth.Text); } }
        public int weightC { get { return Convert.ToInt32(weight.Text); } }
        public int yearsC { get { return Convert.ToInt32(years.Text); } }
        public int sex;
        public int i = 0;





        public int GetIndex(int growthC, int sex)
        {
            int index = growthC - 100 - ((growthC - 150) / sex);
            return index;
        }

        public float GetCaloriesM(float weightC, float growC, float yearsC)
        {
            float NormaCaloriesM = 88.36f + (13.4f * weightC) + (4.8f * growC) - (5.7f * yearsC);
            return NormaCaloriesM;
        }

        public float GetCaloriesW(float weightC, float growC, float yearsC)
        {
            float NormaCaloriesW = 447.6f + (9.2f * weightC) + (3.1f * growC) - (4.3f * yearsC);
            return NormaCaloriesW;
        }

        private void Countbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Man.Checked)
            {
                sex = 2;

                Norma.Text = Convert.ToString(GetCaloriesM(weightC, growC, yearsC));
            }
            else
            {
                sex = 4;

                Norma.Text = Convert.ToString(GetCaloriesW(weightC, growC, yearsC));
            }
            IndexOfBody.Text = Convert.ToString(GetIndex(growC, sex));
        }

        List<int> a = new List<int> ();
        int k = 0;

        private void AddProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Db1Context context = new Db1Context();

            var recepie = context.Recipe;

            var label1 = new Label();
            var label2 = new Label();
            var label3 = new Label();
            var label4 = new Label();
            var label5 = new Label();
            i++;

            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(label1);
            label1.Text = inputProduct.Text;
            flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(label2);
            label2.Text = inputGrams.Text;
            flowLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(label3);
            label3.Text = Convert.ToString(context.Recipe.Where(x => x.Name == inputProduct.Text).Select(x => x.Prop_Time).ToList());
            flowLayoutPanel4.Controls.Add(label4);
            label4.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(label3.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(label2.Text));
            a.Add(Convert.ToInt32(label4.Text));
            flowLayoutPanel5.Controls.Add(label5);
            label5.Text = Convert.ToString(i);
            for ( int p = 0 ;p < a.Count; p++)
            {
                k =+a [p];
            }
            AllCal.Text = Convert.ToString(k);
        }


    }
}
```

Recipe.cs

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Recipe
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Recipe()
        {
            this.RecipeIngredient = new HashSet<RecipeIngredient>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Prop_Time { get; set; }
        public string Instructions { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<RecipeIngredient> RecipeIngredient { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Строка/и в метках непреобразуемa/ы в целое. А где вопрос?

Comment: Извините.Я не понял.

Comment: `label2.Text`, `label3.Text`?

Comment: По скрину очень сильно смущает [`label3.Text`](https://i.imgur.com/A0Ma2QS.png). Ведь не цифра у вас там, а нечто другое...

Comment: Ага, а заносите вы туда лист `label3.Text = Convert.ToString(context.Recipe.Where(x => x.Name == inputProduct.Text).Select(x => x.Prop_Time).ToList()); ` . Не смущает?

Comment: Добавил файл таблицы.Использовал Entity Framework

Comment: @OleksandrTatarinov Скажите, а зачем она нам. Я уже ответит в чем ваша проблема, даже со скрином... Вы пытаетесь `List<>` (коллекцию) засунуть в `string`, что вам в итоге записывает в `label3.Text` - тип, а не значение. Вот скажите `System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.Nullable'1...` - похоже на число? А именно такое значение сейчас у вас в `label3.Text`

Comment: @ EvgeniyZ Понял,спасибо.Сменил на `label3.Text = Convert.ToString(context.Recipe.Where(x => x.Name == inputProduct.Text).Select(x => x.Prop_Time));`Получил ту же ошибку.Можете подсказать как решить проблему?Эта строка выбирает с базы данных Строки в которых название как в `inputProduct.Text`  и берет поле Prop_time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Некий поучительный урок:**

Имеем некую модель данных:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public MyClass(string name, int value)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

И имеем некую коллекцию:

```
var MyCollection = new List<MyClass>
{
    new MyClass("aaaaa", 00000),
    new MyClass("bbbbb", 11111),
    new MyClass("ccccc", 22222)
};
```

Далее мы в переменную попробуем получить некие данные, которые нам нужны:

```
var data1 = MyCollection.Where(x => x.Name == "aaaaa").Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
var data2 = MyCollection.Where(x => x.Name == "aaaaa").Select(x => x.Value);
```

Знакомо, не правда ли? Ну да, ведь это то, что вы пишите в своем кода. Давайте попробуем узнать тип этих двух переменных:

```
Console.WriteLine(data1.GetType());
Console.WriteLine(data2.GetType());
```

На выходе мы получим следующее:

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]
>
> System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[ConsoleApp2.Program+MyClass,System.Int32]

Если по человечески, то у `data1` тип будет в таком виде `List<int>`, а `data2` будет иметь `IEnumerable<int>`. Видно, что обе наши переменные, это коллекции, коллекции обычно содержать несколько элементов внутри себя. К примеру в моем случае, это будет много `int` элементов. Почему? Все просто, ведь в `LINQ` указано `.Select(x => x.Value)`, а x.Value - это значение из класса `MyClass` - `Value`, которое имеет тип `Int`. Другими словами в данном `LINQ` запросе мы взяли у коллекции элементы, где `Name` будет равен `aaaaa`, а далее, в полученных данных, мы забираем только значение `Value`, что в итоге формирует нам объект коллекции типа `IEnumerable<int>`.

Что же будет, если мы коллекцию засунем в некую `string` (чему является ваш `textbox.Text`) - все тоже довольно просто, отдастся тип этой коллекции (как я собственно и вывел выше). Так скажите, это похоже на число? Нет же (либо я что то не понимаю в числах).

**Хорошо, подойдем чуть ближе к решению проблемы:**

1. Не делайте кучу `ConvertTo`, это плохо... Делайте сразу необходимые и правильные типы!
2. `Nullable<int>` - можно просто заменить на int? - ведь удобней, пользуйтесь последними нововведениями языка если есть возможность.
3. `.Where` - вернет всегда коллекцию, даже если найден всего 1 объект.

И так, зная то, что я написал выше, давайте применим это на практике:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? Value { get; set; }

    public MyClass(string name, int? value)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

Тут я изменил `int` на `int?` (что бы знать, равно ли она нулю). Само заполнение коллекции пусть будет также, как и выше. Далее, давайте возьмем одно значение из нашей коллекции, где `Name` будет равен `aaaaa`. Для этого воспользуемся `.FirstOrDefault()`:

```
var data3 = MyCollection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "aaaaa")?.Value;
```

Что за магия тут спросите вы? А все просто... Мы в новую переменную `data3` получаем из коллекции `MyCollection` первый найденный объект (в одном экземпляре), который подходит под параметры "поиска" (а именно, если `Name` равно `aaaaa`). Далее мы из этого объекта (если он не равен нулю (за это отвечает знак `?`)) получаем как и обычно, необходимое нам значение (то есть `Value)`. В таком случае, если у нас не найден объект в коллекции с именем `aaaaa` - в переменной будет `NULL`. Также, если у нас `Value` имеет значение `NULL`, то мы тоже получим его в переменной.

Ну и далее можем работать с чем нам надо и как нам надо. К примеру, прибавим к переменной `+10` и занесем в `TextBox`:

```
int addValue = 10;
if (data3 != null)
    myTextBox.Text = $"{data3 + addValue}";
```

Заметьте, я без проблем сложил `int` и `Nullable<int>`, не надо их конвертировать без надобности. Также я сделал проверку на `NULL`, иначе без нее наше приложение может упасть!!

Вот собственно и все. Удачи в программирование!

Comment: Спасибо за подробное пояснение я все понял, но теперь не работает `Select` .Раньше я с помощью его брал значение `Prop_time`.Как делать мне теперь?

`var recepiedb = context.Recipe.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == inputProduct.Text).Select(x => x.Prop_Time)?.Value;`

Comment: Я же вам в ответе написал про это. `FirstOrDefauld` возвращает вам уже 1 объект. где просто через точку выберите необходимое значение. Вам не надо писать `Select`, а просто после `FirstOrDefauld` пишем `.Prop_Time`